# Specify a variant as argument for holiday in Workday Function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code currently:

```
            Dim holrange1, holrange2 As Range
            Dim holrange As Variant
            Set holrange1 = Sheets("Resource Leave Plan").Range(holday & "4:" & holday & "103")
            Set holrange2 = Sheets("Holidays").Range("B3:B202")
            Set holrange = Nothing
            Set holrange = Range(holrange1.Address & "," & holrange2.Address)
            Worksheets("Schedule").Unprotect Password:="dfss"
            Worksheets("Schedule").Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(strdt, noofdays, holrange)
```

where strdt and noofdays are integers and are already defined. I am getting error 'Unable to get the WorkDay property of WorksheetFunction class'.

I think its because I have set the variant holrange to ranges on two different sheets..

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Are you able to access any other WorksheetFunction?

Comment: yes.. the if I remove holiday argument, everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found this work around.  Since you can use the last parameter as an array I've constructed an array containing the cell values from your two ranges.

I did try using the Union function to join the two ranges into a single range but I couldn't get that to work (because I'm not familiar with using Union).

```
Dim r1, r2 As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim x As Integer

Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A1")  

ReDim r(r1.Count + r2.Count)
x = 0

For Each rCell In r1.Cells
    r(x) = rCell.Value
    x = x + 1
Next rCell

For Each rCell In r2.Cells
    r(x) = rCell.Value
    x = x + 1
Next rCell

MsgBox WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Now(), 1, r)
```